# RVM see gems in gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

How do I view a list of all the gems in a given gemset?  And is it possible to use multiple gemsets at a time or only one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call `gem list` and it will display all the gems in your current gemset. You can only use one gemset at a time, but there is a hierarchy of gemsets. You can create a `global` gemset with (for example) `rake` and `pry` in it, and then any gemset you create (using the same version of ruby, of course) will inherit those gems into it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the current Ruby's @global gemset is [included](https://rvm.io/gemsets/global/) in other gemsets.

To see the contents of a gemset, excluding the @global gemset, first do `rvm use 2.0.0@some-gemset --ignore-gemsets` (or [similar](https://rvm.io/gemsets/ignoring/)) then `gem list`.

For the default gemset, do `rvm use 2.0.0 --ignore-gemsets` then `gem list`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is to query the filesystem. As an example, I had a gemset named `yard` using Ruby 3.0.3. All the gems installed in that gemset could be found with:

```
> ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3@yard/gems
yard-0.9.26
```

(There was just that one gem.)

So the gemset directory name is:

```
~/.rvm/gems/#{ruby_version}@#{gemset_name}/gems
```

...where `ruby_version` is the version rvm uses (i.e. the string output by `rvm list`).